# Inno Setup Exception is not caught

Tags: inno-setup, winhttp, winhttprequest

I am using a domain with an untrusted TLS (SSL) certificate so I could debug something.

This is my code:

```pascal
procedure test();
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
begin
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  try
    WinHttpReq.Open('POST', 'https://tv.eurosport.com/', False);
    WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  
    WinHttpReq.Send('');
  except
    MsgBox(IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status), mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

In case there was an error with the request I would like to print the HTTP status code.

The problem is that the line in the `except` clause is never executed and instead I get the following error:
[image]

Even if I run the executable without debugger attached it still causes errors.

How do I handle an `OleObject` exception in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you expect, the `WinHttpReq.Send` throws

> The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match

That exception is caught by your `except` block. It's not true that the `except` clause is never executed!

In the `except` block you try to read the `WinHttpReq.Status` (HTTP status code). But there's no HTTP status code yet, because the certificate validation happens *before* any HTTP exchange. So the second exception is thrown by the `WinHttpReq.Status` getter:

> WinHttp.WinHttpRequest: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

And you do not have any handler for that. So the exception is caught by the Inno Setup itself and displayed as "Runtime Error".

Comment: Is there any way I could the status code in the except clause for the certificate error?